# Are there meta-plurals beyond "peoples"?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

The plural of "person" is "people".  The plural of "people" is "peoples". Person-people-peoples is the only sequence like this that I know of, but I'm looking for another.

(The equivalent question is, is there another plural noun which has become a singular countable collective noun?)

**EDIT**

For those of you that think that `people` is nothing but a collective noun (and not an irregular plural, like `mice`), I urge you to consider:

- Do you treat other collective nouns as plurals?  One person, two people, but one star, two galaxy?
- Do you treat other plurals as collective nouns?  You can certainly say "a galaxy of stars" but do you say "a mice of mouses"?

For those of you that think the *customary* plural of `person` is `persons`, try it on the next three, uh, persons you see: "Finish this sentence: 'one person, two *_* ?' "

Comment: I don't really get this Q. The plural of the **word** 'person' is 'persons'. 'People' is just a sometime synonym.

Comment: @Fumble he's asking about collective nouns and their plurals, as I see it.

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza: So why go from 'person' to 'people'? I could go star -> galaxy -> cluster -> megacluster -> universe -> multiverse. What's the point?

Comment: *People* is both a simple plural (the plural of *person*) **and** a collective. The two uses have different meanings.

Comment: 1 cop / 2 cops; 1 copse / 2 copses

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Fish*, *fish*, *fishes*: one salmon, one *fish*, two, two *fish*; salmon is one *fish*, haddock another, so two *fishes*. Works with any noun where the singular and plural are irregularly identical, and the regular plural is used for categories or groups; in a more painfully literal fashion, this also applies to words where the plural has become singular in the common case: one *agendum*, two *agenda*; one *agenda*, two *agendas*.

Answer (score 8):

The common plural of *person* is *people*. *Persons* may be common in legalese, but it is very uncommon in day-to-day speech. One normally counts, "one *person*, two *people*, three *people*," etc. When using the word *people* in this way, the word is **not** a collective noun, it is a simple plural.

But *people* is both a plural *and* a collective -- you can say "two people", but you can also say "*a* people". That is normally an identifiable national or ethnic group -- and most assuredly not a simple assemblage of more than one person. It's not a collective noun in quite the same sense that *flock*, *herd* or *murder* is; it usually carries ethnic, racial, linguistic, religious or political overtones to the fore. Used in this way, one can talk of "two *peoples*", "three peoples" and so forth.

As far as I know, the word *people* is unique in that regard.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this entirely meets your criterion, but there is "medium->media->multi-media"....

Comment: bit->byte->kilobyte->megabyte->...?

Comment: No, those are just order of magnitude prefixes above byte.

Comment: I've occasionally seen "medias", which would definitely fit, but I wouldn't consider it standard.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can justify these collective nouns.  Person, people, peoples, for example:  A person is a person.  More than one person, persons.  However, "people" is a group, whether all humans ("people") (plural), or a group ("a people", whether national, ethnic, political, etc.).  We might call the collection of one of these groups "the people" (plural).  So there is the singular "a people", whose plural is "peoples" (or multiple groups), there is the plural term for the collection of a group of "the people", and also there is the plural "people", which is a synonym for "humans".  These words are used thus in these numerous senses, complicating the grammar, so correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

- fish -> shoal -> shoals
- lion -> pride -> prides
- sheep -> herd -> herds
- seagull -> flock -> flocks
- scot -> clan -> clans (yes, I'm pushing it with this example :) )

Basically, many collective nouns are singular and countable. "Peoples" is a bit unintuitive compared to shoals or flocks, for example.

Comment: But *people*, as a plural of *person*, is **not* a collective noun. It doesn't fit this pattern at all.

Comment: @Stan Is it not? What is "The Jewish People"?

Comment: "A couple of Jewish people" is a plural; so is "the Jewish people over there". "*The* Jewish People" is a collective. They're not the same thing, even if the same word is being used.

Comment: @Stan yes, I hadn't read your answer when I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 0):

One answer that might be fun to point out is:

```
single, plural, plurals.
```

But that is trite, and not really correct. However, you could go with:

```
system, systems, meta-system
```

Or some variant of that.

Answer (score 0):

He is not asking about such things as "star, galaxy, galaxies" because the plural for star is *stars*. Some plural nouns are also used as singular nouns in another sense, such as fish, fish, fishes or food, food, foods. Food that you eat is non-count, it has no plural. Food can be singular, however, when used as a synonym for *cusine*. Like this: Asian food, Asian foods. Another example is: Mashed potatoes is food, and a food. Steak and mashed potatoes are food, but they are also two different foods.

Answer (score -2):

> Crow->Murder-> *Murders*

Also:

> Star -> Galaxy -> Galaxies