# "Food" vs. "foods" — spelling and meaning

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, grammatical-number

I've been looking around the Internet. Some websites say that *foods* is incorrect but others say it is correct.

Comment: Hi, Matt_K. I voted to close this question as "general reference" because as it is written, I think you can find a good answer in a dictionary such as [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/food#English) or [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/food). You can learn more in our [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq), including why some questions are closed, as well as find out [how to ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions here!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Food* in its commonest sense is a non-countable noun, with all the effects of that. It's already a plural. You would eat "some food" not "a food". You would say "less food" not "fewer foods".

However, there is a less common usage where "a food" means "a type of food":

> "Cheese is a food made from milk"

... and in this form, you *can* pluralise it ...

> "Italy is the source of many delicious foods -- pizza, pasta, salami, biscotti..."

For comparison, think of "a people" - [Are there meta-plurals beyond "peoples"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/are-there-meta-plurals-beyond-peoples)

Comment: I had a fancy for starting posts and comments with "Peeps," wherever such lingo was tolerated. "Peoples!" doesn't have quite the same ring to it.

Comment: Thanks, which means when we are talking about multiple different number of food, we can use foods?

Comment: _Food_ is **not** plural! The first paragraph in this answer makes no sense and is highly misleading. Yes, _food_ is usually non-count, and that’s why we say ‘some food’ instead of ‘a food’. But it’s quite unambiguously singular, which is exactly why we say ‘less food’ and not ‘fewer food’.

Answer (score 1):

Kraft ***[Foods](http://www.kraftfoodscompany.com/welcome.aspx)*** ... Lots of byspels of the plural for foods. It's common and correct.