# Ownership by other people, but not a collective

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, collective-nouns

How do we write the possessive form for "people?"  For instance, let's say that I manage money for other people.  The people are individuals, here, not a collective (a people).

Which is correct, and why?

> I manage other people's money.

or

> I manage other peoples' money.

**Edit 1**

I suppose the fine line would show itself if I were to say,

> I manage a people's money.

Then "people" becomes a singular collective.  This is not the case for my question.  In general, `'s` seems to be used in singular possessive cases and `s'` in plural possessive cases.  "People," as used here, is a true plural, which would imply the use of `s'`, but that looks odd.

Comment: People is the plural, so then the possessions of the people would be the people's possessions. See this [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/are-there-meta-plurals-beyond-peoples?rq=1)

Comment: Useful link, @LittleEva.  It seems that people could be interpreted as merely having two definitions: plural for person, or a group of individuals who share a trait (e.g. ethnicity).  It still doesn't answer the question, though.  Why would we put `'s` on a word which is plural?

Comment: @gregsdennis to indicate the possessive.  Why wouldn't we put 's on a plural word?

Comment: phoog's got the sense of it, gregsdennis - to indicate possession. For example, at times you manage a person's money, and at other times you manage a number of people's money. There is the People's Republic of China, which is composed of 7 distinct peoples of differing ethnicities,

Comment: But the name of the country is translated that way because it is assumed to imply that all the inhabitants of China are _one_ "people"; otherwise it would be **Peoples' Republic of China**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that you add `'s` to a word to make it posessive, unless the word is a plural that ends in "s" already.  Any style guide will tell you that.  For non-plurals that end in "s" usage varies.  For example, the possessive of *Jesus* is often *Jesus'* but the possessive of *bus* would normally be *bus's.*

The usual example of a plural possessive ending in `'s` is *men's.*

The reason for the different treatment of words ending in *s* depending on whether they are singular or plural is related to pronunciation: the plural ending sounds like the possessive ending, and doubling the sound for plural possessive is awkward.

Answer (score 2):

The first is correct.  The singular "people" can refer to any number of persons.

The only time the plural "peoples" is used is to refer to *multiple* ethnic, national or racial *groups*.

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit.  I'm not asking about the word "people" specifically, but rather its possessive form.

Comment: The possessive form of the uncount mass noun "people" is **people's** as you correctly showed in your first example, which I said is correct. The possessive of the plural count noun "peoples" is **peoples'** which could be apt in other cases (various indigenous peoples' mating customs), but not in the context of your example.