# Singular article usage

Tags: articles

I am baffled by a sentence that I came across in a book recently. "Americans are a very practical people". Why do we need the article "a" here?

Comment: Answered by _bye_ at  [Are there meta-plurals beyond "peoples"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32966/are-there-meta-plurals-beyond-peoples), but lack of research is the obvious problem.

Comment: Try either *The Americans are a…* which refers to the people collectively,  or *Americans are…* which refers to the general characteristics of the group of individuals.

Consider instead, *Negroes are dark-skinned people* as against *The negroes are a dark-skinned people.*

Answer (score 1):

Because, in this sense of the word, 'a people' is equivalent to 'a nation', that is, the inhabitants of a country taken as a whole.